# Python regular expression to extract optional number at the end of string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to write a Python regular expression that can parse strings of the type `"<name>(<number>)"`, where `<number>` is optional.

For example, if I pass `'sclkout'`, then there is no number at the end, so it should just match `'sclkout'`. If the input is `'line7'`, then is should match `'line'` and `'7'`. The name can also contain numbers inside it, so if I give it `'dx3f'`, then the output should be `'dx3f'`, but for `'dx3b0'` it should match `'dx3b'` and `0`.

This is what I first tried:

```
import re

def do_match(signal):
    match = re.match('(\w+)(\d+)?', signal)
    assert match
    print "Input = " + signal
    print "group1 = " + match.group(1)
    if match.lastindex == 2:
        print "group2 = " + match.group(2)
    print ""


# should match 'sclkout'
do_match("sclkout")

# should match 'line' and '7'
do_match("line7")

# should match 'dx4f'
do_match("dx4f")

# should match 'dx3b' and '0'
do_match("dx3b0")
```

This is of course wrong because of greedy matching in the `(\w+)` group, so I tried setting that to non-greedy:

```
match = re.match('(\w+?)(\d+)?', signal)
```

This however only matches the first letter of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a possessive quantifier like this:

```
^(?<name>\w+?)(?<number>\d+)?$
```

Or `^(\w+?)(\d+)?$`, if you don't want the named capture groups.

See live demo here: http://rubular.com/r/44Ntc4mLDY

Comment: This even works like this `(\w+?)(\d+)?$`, without caring for the beginning of the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this:

```
from itertools import takewhile
def do_match(s):
    num = ''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit, reversed(s)))[::-1]
    return s[:s.rindex(num)], num
... 
>>> do_match('sclkout')
('sclkout', '')
>>> do_match('line7')
('line', '7')
>>> do_match('dx4f')
('dx4f', '')
>>> do_match('dx3b0')
('dx3b', '0')
```

Comment: I'd replace `s[::-1]` with `reversed(s)` (clearer and more memory efficient).

Comment: @Bakuriu Surely, not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

`([a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]*)` is what you want.

```
import re
test = ["sclkout", "line7", "dx4f", "dx3b0"]
ans  = [("sclkout", ""), ("line", "7"), ("dx4f", ""), ("dx3b", "0")]

for t, a in zip(test, ans):
    m = re.match(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]*)', t)
    if m.groups() == a:
        print "OK"
    else:
        print "NG"
```

output:

```
OK
OK
OK
OK
```